# Having some problems with regular expression

Tags: php, preg-match-all

in PHP: How can I put a variable in a regular expression.

Something like this:

```
$var = "Some text";
$regular_expression = '/\d.*h/' . $var . '/hw/';
```

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly like that, just don't use the extra delimiters. `$regular_expression = '/\d.*h' . $var . 'hw/';`

Comment: Ok, thank you colburton

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstration of two ways to write a variable into a regex pattern:

Code: ([Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/831fcc0e13dadce187eeb6db00d0b99d8dbf2da2))

```
$string='8_hSome texthw 9_hSome texthw';
$var = "Some text";

//Single quoted pattern with dot-concatenation:
$regex1= '/\d.*h' . $var . 'hw/';
var_export(preg_match_all($regex1,$string,$out)?$out:'failed');

echo "\n---\n";

// Double quoted pattern with curly bracketed variable isolation:
$regex2= "/\d.*h{$var}hw/";
var_export(preg_match_all($regex2,$string,$out)?$out:'failed');

// note the greedy quantifier (*) matches 1 long substring, instead of two short substrings
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '8_hSome texthw 9_hSome texthw',
  ),
)
---
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '8_hSome texthw 9_hSome texthw',
  ),
)
```